# Oracle : how to display second or third letter in each word of sentence as CAPITAL letter in Oracle

Tags: oracle

how to display second or third letter in each word of sentence as CAPITAL letter in Oracle.

Testdata:
hyderabad

Output:
hYderabad or hyDerabad

Comment: Second or third? You got to choose 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for `2nd` digit as upper case.

```
  WITH TBL(TESTDATA) AS
  ( SELECT 'hyderabad' FROM DUAL UNION
   SELECT 'pune' FROM DUAL UNION
   SELECT '223jjjj22' FROM DUAL
   )
   SELECT substr(testdata,1,1)||upper(substr(testdata,2,1))
   ||substr(testdata,3,length(testdata)-2) 
    as output 
   FROM TBL
```

Output

```
223jjjj22
hYderabad
pUne
```

Here I fetched first character,upper case of second character and rest of characters separately. Then I concatenated them.

You can use similar approach for `3rd` character if you want.

Answer (score 1):

To make 2nd character to upper case

```
select SUBSTR(test_data,1,1)||INITCAP(SUBSTR(test_data,2)) from test_table;
```

To make the 3rd character to upper case, increment the last argument of both SUBSTR with 1.

Example

```
select SUBSTR(test_data,1,2)||INITCAP(SUBSTR(test_data,3)) from test_table;
```

Comment: Good approach with `INITCAP` function.